# Slow sql query if i have out param

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

If i call stored procedure only with SQLSRV_PARAM_IN params, then my script run in 1-3sec, query to base less 1sec.
Example (i want create pagination)

```
    $DocsCount = 0;
$query = "EXEC DBO.ElDocAllFTSWithPages @DocsCount = ?, @OffSet =?, @PerPage = ?, @FindStr = ?";
$params = array(
    array(&$DocsCount, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
    array(&$start, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$perPage->perpage, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$searchtext, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
);
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, $params, array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));
if( !$stmt ) {
    print "ERROR";
}
$result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
if( !$result ) {
    // show errors
}
$data = array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

I get succefull $DocsCount (total rows in query) and array with rows limited by $perpage. But very slow (20-40sec).
If i rewrite script and sql-query and remove array(&$DocsCount, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT) it is run 1-3sec

```
    $DocsCount = 0;
$start = 0;
$perpage = 500;

$sql = "EXEC DBO.ElDocAllFTSWithPages @OffSet =?, @PerPage = ?, @FindStr = ?";
$params = array(
    array(&$start, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$perpage, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$searchtext, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
);
$getsearchdocs = new GetSearchDocs();
$foundeddocs = $getsearchdocs->loadsearchdocs($sql,$params);
```

On sql server both queries run 1-2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

```
..buffered.. "Lets you access rows in any order. Creates a client-side cursor query."
```

I can't see the reason for establishing this type of connection to PHP under your circumstances. You're looping forward, storing results in the array, so the default cursor "forward" would suffice.

regards,